# simple function to return the type

Tags: python, types

I wanted to write a simple little function to return the type to me. Unfortunately i get all those indentation errors( i use sublime text 2... no idea why i get those all the time)

```
def get_the_type(value):
if value== "NULL" or value=="":
    return(type(None))
elif (value=="{"): 
    return (type([]))
elif isinstance(value,(int)):
    return type(1))
elif isinstance(value,(float)):
    return(type(1.1))
else:
    return (type("bla"))
```

Can someone tell me where my error is ?

Comment: All the lines after the `def` line must be indended with an additional space/tab

Comment: Looking at the code you posted, there seemed to be a mixture of tabs and spaces, that will cause you to rip your hair out in Python

Comment: @StephanKetterer your real error is missing `(` in `return type(1))` - remember the error message usually points to the line that is at fault - if not if *might* be missing punctuation in the line before.  This is a typo and it rightly marked as such.  However, in future, you really need to edit your post to get the indentation looking right (exactly as it does in your editor), otherwise no-one will be able to answer your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indent inside the def and remove the extra paren:

```
def get_the_type(value):
    if value== "NULL" or  value ==  "":
        return "NoneType"
    elif value == "{": 
        return "dict" # maybe set?
    elif isinstance(value,  int):
        return "int" # <- removed )
    elif isinstance(value, float):
        return "float"
    else:
        return "str"
```

Not sure if you want to use the type or just see what type it is, if you just want to see the type use strings as above. Also `[]` is a list and you have `{` as the value so that should maybe be a dict or set.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing indentation of the if statement relative to the function definition.

Comment: No, it was just formatted wrong here. This is how my code looks : http://pastebin.com/M8YiErXa , can anybody help me ?